# How to create a list from urls that was concatenated in a loop?

Tags: python, list

My goal is put all my urls into a list. I had concatenate them after looping through a number list, as an example:

The code that I've written:

```
number_list = [1, 2, 3]
url_list = []

for i in number_list:
  url_string_concat = 'www.example.url/=' + str(i)
  url_list.append(url_string_concat)

  print(url_list)
```

I expected output to be:

```
  url_list = ['www.example.url/=1', 'www.example.url/=2', 'www.example.url/=3']
```

However, the result that I obtain was:

```
['www.example.url/=1'] ['www.example.url/=1', 'www.example.url/=2'] ['www.example.url/=1', 'www.example.url/=2', 'www.example.url/=3']
```

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: You're printing from inside the loop

Comment: just move the print outside the loop and you find that everything is fine

Comment: all it requires is 4 backspaces....

Comment: Hold on, no body is gonna pay attention to the fact that .url turned to .cm magically?

Comment: @LazyCoder I think thats a copy paste error

Comment: Sorry but I can't help myself: do it in one print: `print(["www.example.url/=" + str(i) for i in number_list])`

Comment: @LazyCoder yes typo, edited original post to focus on issue on hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're calling `print` on every iteration

```
number_list = [1, 2, 3]
url_list = []

for i in number_list:
    url_string_concat = 'www.example.url/=' + str(i)
    url_list.append(url_string_concat)

print(url_list)
```

output

```
['www.example.url/=1', 'www.example.url/=2', 'www.example.url/=3']
```

or you can simplify your code with list comprehension:

```
url_list = ['www.example.url/={}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 4)]
```

output:

```
url_list
['www.example.url/=1', 'www.example.url/=2', 'www.example.url/=3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `print` statement occurs on every iteration. Here would be adding in a print statement at the end of the iteration as well -- which is where your expected result would occur:

```
number_list = [1, 2, 3]
url_list = []
for i in number_list:
    url_string_concat = 'www.example.url/=' + str(i)
    url_list.append(url_string_concat)
    print("Running num %s ==> %s" % (i, url_list))


print ("Done ==> %s" % url_list)
```

And you'd get:

```
Running num 1 ==> ['www.example.url/=1']
Running num 2 ==> ['www.example.url/=1', 'www.example.url/=2']
Running num 3 ==> ['www.example.url/=1', 'www.example.url/=2', 'www.example.url/=3']
Done ==> ['www.example.url/=1', 'www.example.url/=2', 'www.example.url/=3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is okay, the list is concatenated correctly, but you print it on every iteration so you see as it is growing.
@frankegoesdown showed you a corrected code.
You can also use list comprehensions

```
url_list = ['www.example.url/=' + str(i) for i in range(1, 4)]
print(url_list)
```